# pip install without upgrading a specific dependency

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to pip install a library that has a lot of dependencies. I have a patched version of one dependency that I would like not updated when I install the library. How can I prevent this patched dependency from being updated?

---

(Specifically, I want to pip install `fastai` without upgrading my version of `torch`, but do install other dependencies required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install this dependency before running pip install it won't install it again.

This means to you can install your patched version and then your package:

For instance:

**From pypi with another version**

```
pip install requests==2.17.0
pip install kinto
```

**From a Git branch**

```
git clone git@github.com:kennethreitz/requests.git
pip install -e requests
pip install kinto
```

**From a egg or a wheel**

```
wget https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/archive/v2.21.0.tar.gz
pip install v2.21.0.tar.gz
pip install kinto
```

Comment: I can't pip install the dependency bc the patched version is not available on pip. I found a workaround by using --no-deps and then just pip installing all the other dependencies minus the one I didn't want to update.

Comment: The patch version doesn't have to be on pypi to install it.